# Quoting Films in an essay using MLA

Tags: essay, mla

I am trying to quote a film (Monty Python and the Holy Grail) in an MLA format essay, and I am not quite sure how to go about it. I have figured out how to cite it (both in the essay and in a Works Cited page), but I am not sure how to quote the dialogue.

If the script looks like this:

> Person X: Blahblahblah
>
> Person Y: Floopdeloop

How would I go about quoting that in the body of the essay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to break the quote up with words of your own, if you're using two distinct lines of dialogue.

eg. This absurdist humour is evident when Character X goes to great lengths to explain "Blahblahblah," and Person Y responds with a dry "Floopdeloop" (MLA citation).

If there are important physical actions that are not conveyed in the dialogue, you can add that in your own words.

eg. This absurdist humour is evident when Character X goes to great lengths to explain "Blahblahblah," and Person Y responds with a dry "Floopdeloop" while slapping Character X in the face with a medium-sized fish (MLA citation).

It's pretty much how you'd quote anything else, I'd say.